# Prevent wifi from disconnecting on bad signal

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, connection

My wifi connection is bad (on the border of the reachable area). It disconnects from time to time, but virtually always reconnects somewhere within 10 seconds (at a bad signal nevertheless).

Programs that use the internet connections disconnect when Windows shuts off its connection. Is there a way to increase the timeout length for wifi connections, or make it not disconnect even if the signal is VERY bad or unreachable for a period of time?

(A more general possible solution would also be: never disconnect from Wifi no matter the connection quality.)
(A possible solution would be: stay connected to a virtual adapter that forwards all connections from the actual Wifi adapter but remains working (queueing) when the Wifi connection gets disconnected for a period of time)

I haven't found anything that seems to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a Wireless Device no longer has enough signal to stay connected, it will disconnect. There is nothing you can do about that and there is not any way to keep the wireless device connected if there is not enough signal.

So that is the direct answer to your question.

You can perhaps try a more sensitive card to see if that helps. You could try a USB Wireless Card, for example. Even a more sensitive card will disconnect in the absence of signal.

Comment: I still feel like there might be a solution where applications that use the internet connection do not receive a signal or otherwise notice that the connection has been interrupted (because they are connected to a virtual adapter), where the virtual adapter queues and sends any information via a real network adapter that may be disconnected at times.

I don't know anything about virtual devices or anything below the application layer, so this is the best answer for now, thank you! And maybe someone with the necessary expertise and the same problem might step up one day.

Comment: We will see if someone adds something. My long experience with wireless (spanning decades) was the basis for my answer above.